# polylang auto switch language by user data

Tags: wordpress, plugins, polylang

There is a site with installed and created two languages - english and italian.
From the user I get information from which country he is in the format - 'en', 'it'

Tell me how to set the site language for the user based on the received data.
Or make a redirect to the required language version.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to post this as a comment, but did you try to activate this from from the Polylang settings -> Detect browser language ?